# Java Swing Location On Screen after Resize

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to keep a JDialog centered inside of a JFrame, regardless if the JFrame is moved or resized.

Essentially, I have a class like (This is not the real code, just an example )

```
 import javax.swing.*;        
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;

public class HelloWorldSwing extends ComponentAdapter implements   AncestorListener {


private JDialog dialog;

private JFrame frame;

@Override
public void componentResized( ComponentEvent event ) {
    //This value does not hcange when dragged from the left or right
    System.err.println( " Location " + frame.getLocationOnScreen() );
    recenter();
}    

@Override
public void ancestorAdded( AncestorEvent evt ) {

}

@Override
public void ancestorRemoved( AncestorEvent evt ) {

}

@Override
public void ancestorMoved( AncestorEvent evt ) {
    //This value does not hcange when dragged from the left or right
    System.err.println( " Location " + frame.getLocationOnScreen() );
    recenter();
}

private void recenter() {
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo( frame.getRootPane() );
}


/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getRootPane().addAncestorListener( this );
    frame.getRootPane().setBackground( Color.WHITE );        
    frame.addComponentListener( this );
    frame.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 500, 500 ) );
    frame.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 500, 500 ) );

    dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setResizable( true );
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
    dialog.setVisible( true );
    dialog.setMaximumSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
    dialog.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            HelloWorldSwing swing = new HelloWorldSwing();
            swing.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

When the JFrame is resized from the left or the top, the location on the screen changes, but the getLocationOnScreen() does not change it's result. It seems like the getLocationOnScreen should change as the top left corner has changed due to a resize.

What am I missing ? Thanks.

Update ::

This code seems to run fine on Windows, but does not run correctly on Fedora 21, java 7

Comment: When I try to reproduce this, it works fine for me. Please consider providing a runnable example (see [mcve]). Btw, `dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);` would also be a way to center the dialog relative to the frame.

Comment: I agree, just use the setLocationRelativeTo(...) method.